# Why cast null to Object?

Tags: java, null

I found a spot in some code I'm working on where `null` is cast to `Object` as it is passed to a method.

Why would this be done?

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315846/why-null-cast) which deals with overloaded methods, and using the cast to determine which version of the method to call.

But if the cast were not performed, wouldn't an overloaded method with a parameter typed as `Object` be chosen over any other matching version of the method if the method is called with a null argument?  So what else does the cast accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why null cast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315846/why-null-cast)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If the cast where **not** performed, then the **most specific** version would be chosen.

`null` could be a null-reference of type `String` or of type `Object`. So if those two methods are available, then the `String` method will be called.

If you have methods with `Object`, `Integer` **and** `String` then calling that with `null` (and no cast) would give a compilation error because `Integer` and `String` are both valid and **equally specific** (i.e. none is a specialization of the other). In that case you would **have** to cast `null` to specify which method to call.

Comment: Though I agree with your answer but I believe the first statement is not correctly put i.e. compiler always try to locate the most specific match if more than one method is applicable, for example, if you cast null to say Integer and you have overloaded method with Object type and Number type argument respectively then it will resolve to one with Number type (i.e. the most specific one).

Answer (score 14):

The "`Object` method" is always the "least specific" method among all "applicable methods". That's why it wouldn't be chosen by the compiler.

If you run

```
String.valueOf(null);
```

Then the compiler has the choice of two "applicable methods". You're actually calling the more specific method

```
String.valueOf((char[]) null);
```

Which will give you a `NullPointerException`. In order to call the other method, write

```
String.valueOf((Object) null);
```

In this case, you remain with only one "applicable method", so you don't have the problem of a different, overloaded method being "more specific".

Comment: +1 for `String.valueOf(Object o)` is "least specific" match among all possible matches. However, it would make sense to also mention that in case of String if no specific cast is done then the "most specific" match we are left with is `String.valueOf(Char [] c)` and thus it gets called. **Note:** java compiler always resolves overloaded methods to the one with "most specific" match and if it fails to do so it will give 'reference to method is ambiguos' compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Though previous answers already explains what happens if you cast null to Object vs.  if you don't cast null to Object, but I would still like to add few missing points.

So in Java, 'arrays' are objects which means they can be assigned to Object type i.e. if you do `new char[0].getClass().getSuperclass()` it gives `java.lang.Object` and therefore in case when null is not explicitly cast compiler chooses `valueOf(char[])` over `valueOf(Object)` as the most applicable method.

However, **here comes the missing part**, had there been another overloaded method that was accepting a interface type param (**remember interface don't extend Object class so they too cause ambiguity in most specific method selection**) e.g. valueOf(CharSequence) then this would have lead to compile time error (i.e. reference to valueOf is ambiguous) because then compiler could't pick the most applicable method.

So the bottom line is **avoid passing raw null** as arguments to methods rather always cast them to param type of the method being called. :)

Answer (score -2):

"But if the cast were not performed, wouldn't an overloaded method with a parameter typed as Object be chosen over any other matching version of the method if the method is called with a null argument? "

No, because 'null' has no type - you'd get a compilation error.

Comment: Wrong. You **only** get a compilation error if there is more than one "most specific" overload around.

Comment: I was taking it as assumed that he had more than one method, it's sort of embedded in the question.