# why output String passed not object

Tags: java, string, object

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    magic(null);
}

public static void magic(String s) {
    System.out.println("String passed");
}

public static void magic(Object o) {
    System.out.println("object passed");
}
}
```

why string passed printed not object passed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why cast null to Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806163/why-cast-null-to-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> **The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.**

Comment: In partiular, if you'd add (say) `void magic(Integer s)`, then the program wouldn't compile anymore, since then it would be ambigous as to what the more specific method would be.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't type cast, it is chosen upon the most specific.
`null` can be reference of type `String` or an `Object`.
So, if both are available then the String method will be called.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        magic(null);
    }

    public static void magic(Object o) {
        System.out.println("object passed");
    }

    public static void magic(String s) {
        System.out.println("String passed");
    }

    public static void magic(Integer s) {
        System.out.println("Integer passed");
    }
}
```

This would no longer compile,

It would say : Ambiguous method call. Both `magic(String)` and `magic(Integer)` in test match