# Android Error Creating custom list view with volley jar

Tags: android

I'm using `volley jar` to create `customListView` below is the code i have used to implement . I have get this from [open](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/).

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inventory, container, false);

            button=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    displayView(7);
                    //launchQRScanner(view);
                }
            });

            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), inventoryList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // Showing progress dialog before making http request
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.show();

            Log.d("Url: ",url);

            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest inventoryReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();
                            try {
                            JSONObject obj1 = response.getJSONObject(1);
                            int status = obj1.getInt("status");
                            if(status==1) {

                                JSONArray data=obj1.getJSONArray("data");
                                // Parsing json
                                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
                                    inventory.setNickName(obj.getString("nickname"));
                                    inventory.setThumbUrl(obj.getString("thumb"));
                                    inventory.setStockNumber(obj.getString("apron_id"));
                                    inventory.setDOP(obj.getString("Date_purchase"));
                                    inventory.setColor(obj.getString("color"));

                                    // adding movie to movies array
                                    inventoryList.add(inventory);


                                }
                            }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("JSON","JSON ERROR"+e.getMessage());
                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                    Log.d("JSON ERROR",error.getMessage());
                                    hidePDialog();

                                }
                          });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(inventoryReq);

            return rootView;

        }
```

**Logcat**

```
04-28 11:31:10.819  18300-18498/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 413K, 13% free 8257K/9479K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
04-28 11:31:10.827  18300-18300/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/Volley﹕ [1] 3.onErrorResponse: MainActivity
04-28 11:31:10.827  18300-18300/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/JSON ERROR﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value {"data":[{"apron_id":"123456","created_user":"2","Expiration":"2015-04-23","location":"13","nickname":"uyi","UID_no":"ikujki","Date_purchase":"2015-04-10","Batch":"ikk","update_time":"2015-04-10 05:22:38","color":"juki","manufacture":"0","garment_type":"yuyh","QTY":"898","core_material":"ytyt","created_time":"2015-04-10 05:22:38","apron_status":"0","inventory_id":"33","thumb":"http:\/\/demo.com\/test\/facility\/images\/no_photo.jpg","serial":"iui","apron_retire":"0"},{"apron_id":"12345mn","created_user":"2","Expiration":"2015-03-17","location":"12","nickname":"gfhgh","UID_no":"rtryttttttttt","Date_purchase":"2015-04-28","Batch":"rtrrtyy","update_time":"2015-04-10 05:15:54","color":"ytgtfghtg","manufacture":"0","garment_type":"hgjyhj","QTY":"7688","core_material":"fhgfhy","created_time":"2015-04-10 05:15:54","apron_status":"0","inventory_id":"32","thumb":"http:\/\/demo.com\/test\/facility\/images\/no_photo.jpg","serial":"hfh","apron_retire":"0"},{"apron_id":"12345df","created_user":"2","Expiration":"2015-05-15","location":"12","nickname":"rytyutu","UID_no":"rr546","Date_purchase":"2015-02-11","Batch":"rgf5676","update_time":"2015-04-10 04:50:45","color":"grey23","manufacture":"0","garment_type":"smooth","QTY":"45","core_material":"core2","created_time":"2015-04-10 04:50:45","apron_status":"0","inventory_id":"28","thumb":"http:\/\/demo.com\/test\/facility\/images\/no_photo.jpg","serial":"fgtg6","apron_retire":"0"},{"apron_id":"12345gh","created_user":"2","Expiration":"2015-03-12","location":"6","nickname":"hjytreeeeet","UID_no":"4566","Date_purchase":"2015-04-28","Batch":"gf545646","update_time":"2015-04-10 04:52:28","color":"green1","manufacture":"0","garment_type":"rtr","QTY":"57","core_material":"core3","created_time":"2015-04-10 04:52:28","apron_status":"0","inventory_id":"29","thumb":"http:\/\/demo.com\/test\/facility\/images\/no_photo.jpg","serial":"tyy567","apron_retire":"0"},{"apron_id":"12345jk","created_user":"2","Expiration":"2015-05-07","location":"5","nickname":"hhhhiiiii","UID_no":"gf465","Date_purchase":"2015-04-30","Batch":"tg4657","update_time":"2015-04-10 04:53:35","color":"yello7","manufacture":"0","garment_type":"thick","QTY":"89","core_material":"core4","created_time":"2015-04-10 04:53:35","apron_status":"0","inventory_id":"30","thumb":"http:\/\/demo.com\/test\/facility\/images\/no_photo.jpg","serial":"5rtgr","apron_retire":"0"},{"apron_id":"12345kl","created_user":"2","Expiration":"2015-08-14","location":"5","nickname":"hhjhj","UID_no":"rrrrrrr","Date_purchase":"2015-04-17","Batch":"hghh","update_time":"2015-04-10 05:14:57","color":"ytytyt","manufacture":"0","garment_type":"jyjjyj","QTY":"65765","core_material":"fghf","created_time":"2015-04-10 05:14:57","apron_status":"0","inventory_id":"31","thumb":"http:\/\/demo.com\/test\/facility\/images\/no_photo.jpg","serial":"fh","apron_retire":"0"},{"apron_id":"67675687866","created_user":"2","Expiration":"2018-05-08","location":"13","nickname":"tyujyhj","UID_no":"yujyhjy","Date_purchase":"2015-05-08","Batch":"ytyty","update_time":"2015-04-23 07:15:06","color":"hhjyj","manufacture":"14","garment_type":"yujyhjyu","QTY":"2147483647","core_material":"hhjh","created_time":"2015-04-10 05:27:02","apron_status":"0","inventory_id":"37","thumb":"http:\/\/demo.com\/test\/facility\/images\/no_photo.jpg","serial":"t yt","apron_retire":"0"},{"apron_id":"12345as","created_user":"2","Expiration":"2015-06-30","location":"13","nickname":"nick","UID_no":"3546re","Date_purchase":"2015-04-01","Batch":"3454fgf","update_time":"2015-04-10 04:49:10","color":"black","manufacture":"0","garment_type":"pure1","QTY":"42","core_material":"core1","created_time":"2015-04-10 04:49:10","apron_status":"0","inventory_id":"27","thumb":"http:\/\/demo.com\/test\/facility\/images\/no_photo.jpg","serial":"2323","apron_retire":"0"},{"apron_id":"89745465798416467987","created_user":"2","Expiration":"1969-12-31","location":"12","nickname":"test","UID_no":"35678"
```

No Listing comming because of this error

```
 [1] 3.onErrorResponse: MainActivity
```

Please suggest me your views. Thanks in advance.

I have changed `JSONArrayRequest` to `JSONObjectRequest`  New Error comes.

[image: please see screen]

Answer (score 3):

### Mistake:

It's giving `JSONException` because you are trying to parse the response into the `JSONArray`, whereas server is returning response packaged into the `JSONObject`.

```
JsonArrayRequest inventoryReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,(String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                             ............. 
                             .............
}
```

### Solution:

Handle `JSONObject` in `onResponse()` method.

```
JsonObjectRequest inventoryReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            int status = response.getInt("status");
            if(status == 1){
                JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data")
                for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    //Do something
                }

         }catch(...){
         ...
         }
    }
    ........ ........ ........
    ........ ........ ........
```

Comment: Response coming from server is correct i have checked at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) also

Comment: I have checked the response you posted in the question. Take care of putting correct details into your question!

Comment: @manikantag updated answer again! Requesting you to put correct details otherwise it would be a wastage of other time and you may even not get perfect answer quickly!

Comment: @PareshMayani rogerthat

Comment: @PareshMayani  JSON is not formatted properly, Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: @manikanta , Like Paresh said, modify your code. Instead of JsonArrayRequest, use JsonObjectRequest. It will work then.

Comment: @rogerthatcode no check my answer history details, that's what I misunderstood based on the response details he has included in the question, but if you check the response then you would realise that JSON response is formatted properly and so strings are already wrapped into the double quotes.

Comment: @PareshMayani  i have update code with your suggestion. please see the post i have updated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247525/why-is-my-jsonobjectrequest-not-working/29255606#29255606 this will help

Comment: @rogerthatcode in that case you have edited my answer with incorrect code :)

Comment: @PareshMayani oops! syntex error.. plese review and accept the correct syntex. Thanks :)

Comment: @rogerthatcode I was about to update the answer with the same details but meanwhile you did it. Thanks