# Comparable and (MyClass)null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, compare, comparable

Say I have

```
public class MyClass 
     implements Comparable<MyClass>
{
    public int compareTo(MyClass mc)
    {
        //<implementation ommited>...
    }
}
```

The docs for Comparable say that "The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. **Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException** even though e.equals(null) returns false."

it says that "**e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException**".

Should it throw NullPointerException also when doing `e.compareTo((MyClass)null)`?

Comment: Yeah, that's still a null value. You shouldn't often need to cast a null; that'd only be where there was an overloaded method. The slight distinction is further described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315846/why-null-cast .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should throw a NullPointerException.

`null` is `null` at runtime, no matter what type you give it at compile-time.

Your code has no way to figure out if you called `e.compareTo((MyClass)null)` or `e.compareTo(null)`. It's the same.

Answer (score 2):

What difference does it make if you write `e.compareTo(null)` or `e.compareTo((MyClass)null)`?

Both code are one and the same, as `null is null. Even if you cast it to any type, it will be null only`.

Comment: `null` can be cast to *all* types.